# Spring RedirectAttributes results in "Cannot create a session after the response has been committed" error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Adding a redirect attributes to a flash map results in following exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2377)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2097)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:833)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.DefaultFlashMapManager.retrieveFlashMaps(DefaultFlashMapManager.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.DefaultFlashMapManager.requestCompleted(DefaultFlashMapManager.java:202)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:830)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
```

This is what my request handler look like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getFoo(RedirectAttributes attr) {
  attr.addFlashAttribute("twiddle", "doodle");
  return "redirect:/cow";
}
```

Does anyone know what causes this / how to debug the problem?

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation, turns out the JSP view that served the form that posts into /foo had `session=false` page directive attribute like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"  session="false" %>
```

Spring redirect attributes utilizes HttpSession object, and that attribute causes HttpSession generation to be skipped. After removing that attribute / setting it to true, the redirect works fine

Answer (score 1):

To better understand problem see this link
http://nirlevy.blogspot.com/2007/09/requestdispatcherforward-and-filters.html
Add more

```
<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
```

in web.xml.It will work.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant. The cause of the problem was when I added values into the flashMapAttributes, there isn't any HttpSession object available. In Spring MVC post-redirect-get pattern, HttpSession is used to shortly store the attributes before they're fetched after redirection completes

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that on your configuration files, the urls begin with a foward slash i.e. '/' e.g '/index.jsp'.